# threading not update module time

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-multithreading

i'm new to python and i wrote a simple code just to run in sequence time and send email when is trigger. 
i use threading timer for counting and import outbound.py (with import datetime) just to clean up the main scrip so it will not have email scrip in main.py. however when the first email received, the message time reflect correctly but the next email remain the same time from first email.

below is the main.py scrip

```
import threading
from outbound import outbound

def run ():
    threading.Timer(10,run).start()
    outbound()   
run()
```

outbound.py scrip

```
from datetime import datetime   
now=datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

def outbound():    
   print (dt_string)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created `dt_string` when you imported the module, and never updated it again. Move the string initialization into the function body.

```
def outbound():    
    dt_string = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    print (dt_string)
```